# How to copy/print/export Excel 2013 powerview sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I copy Excel 2013 PowerView sheet to for example PowerPoint slide?

Or if I try to export it to pdf-file I get a message in pdf:

```
"Power View can only print one sheet at a time.
 Please switch to the desired sheet and try again."
```

I have only one sheet in my workbook.

I could use a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, there is not an option to export a Power View visualization from within Excel 2013.  When you select the "Save As" menu option, there are numerous formats, but PowerPoint is not one of them.

One way I can think of to get the Power View visualization into a PDF is to use a "PDF Printer" program, which acts as a system printer and can convert anything you can print into a PDF.  There are a number of freeware and shareware PDF Printer softwares available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you you are really asking; how to get Power View data to PowerPoint or a PDF file.

Either way, it would appear you can not copy them directly to a PDF. As far as I can tell, you need to the `File` menu and `Export to PowerPoint` first. From there you can edit the presentation as desired, then the presentation can be saved it to a PDF.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759323.aspx)

Comment: Either way would be nice. PowerPoint or PDF. Point is to get it somewhere. Your source is referring to PowerView on Sharepoint. I'm talking about PowerView on Excel 2013.

Comment: Do you even have the option to export to PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can export from Sharepoint's Power View to Powerpoint, and You can export from Excel's Power View to PDF.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx#_Toc367108158

Comment: Probably a short procedure describing the export would be useful here.